# Finding multiple links in a linked list

Tags: java, linked-list

> The current find method works well but only for one node. If I try for example find("London") and more nodes that fulfill the condition it returns only the first one.What must i modify for it to return all the nodes that fulfill the condition ?

```
public class LinkList {

public Link first; // ref to first link on list

public LinkList() // constructor
{
    first = null; // no links on list yet
}

 public void insert(Object Airplanefnumber,Object Airplanedest, Object Airplaneline, Object Airplaneplane, Object Airplanetime, Object Terminal, Object Parkingslot)
{ // make new link
    Link newLink = new Link(Airplanefnumber, Airplanedest, Airplaneline, Airplaneplane, Airplanetime, Terminal, Parkingslot);
    newLink.next = first; // it points to old first link
    first = newLink; // now first points to this

}
public void insertqueue(Object Airplanefnumber,Object Airplanedest, Object Airplaneline, Object Airplaneplane, Object Airplanetime, Object Terminal, Object Parkingslot, Object Runway)
{ // make new link
    LinkQueue newLink = new LinkQueue(Airplanefnumber, Airplanedest, Airplaneline, Airplaneplane, Airplanetime, Terminal, Parkingslot, Runway);
   // newLink.next = first; // it points to old first link
   // first = newLink; // now first points to this
}


public Link find(String key) // find link with given key
{ // (assumes non-empty list)
    Link current = first; // start at FIRST

    while( !current.Airplanedest.equals(key)) // while no match,
    {

     if(current.next == null) // if end of list,
            return null; // did not find it
        else // not end of list,
            current = current.next; // go to next link

}
return current;
}





public Link findnumber(int key) // find link with given key
{ // (assumes non-empty list)
    Link current = first; // start at FIRST
    while(!(current.Airplanefnumber.equals(key))) // while no match,
    {
        if(current.next == null) // if end of list,
            return null; // did not find it
        else // not end of list,
            current = current.next; // go to next link
    }
    return current; // found it



}




public Link delete(int key) // delete link with given key
{ // (assumes non-empty list)
    Link current = first; // search for link
    Link previous = first;

    while(!(current.Airplanefnumber).equals(key))
    {
        if(current.next == null)
            return null; // did not find it
        else
        {
            previous = current; // go to next link

        }
        current = current.next;
    } // found it

    if(current == first) // if first link,
        first = first.next; // change first
    else // otherwise,
        previous.next = current.next; // bypass it
    return current;
}


public void displayList() // display the list
{

    System.out.println();
    Link current = first; // start at beginning of list
    while(current != null) // until end of list,
    {
        current.displayLink(); // print data

        current = current.next; // move to next link
    }
   // System.out.println("Flight Number is: "+ flightnumber +"\n"+"Flight destination is:"+ destination +"\n"+ "Airline: "+ airline +"\n"+"Airplane: "+ airplane +"\n"+"Schedule time: "+ time);

    System.out.println("");
}

 public void peekFirst()  
 {  
   System.out.println(first.Airplanefnumber + "\n" +first.Airplanedest + "\n" + first.Airplaneline + "\n" + first.Airplaneplane + "\n" +  first.Airplanetime + "\n" + first.Terminal + "\n" + first.Parkingslot);
} 


public boolean isEmpty()  
{  
  return(first==null);  
}  
} //end of LinkList class


  //code from main

  Link f = null;
  System.out.println("Enter flight destination");
  String dest = input.nextLine();
  System.out.println("You entered destination "+ dest);
  f = Planes.find(dest);
  if( f != null){
    System.out.println("Flight number: "+f.Airplanefnumber +"\n"+"Flight destination is:"+f.Airplanedest+"\n"+"Airline: "+f.Airplaneline+"\n"+"Airplane type: "+f.Airplaneplane+"\n"+"Scheduled time: "+f.Airplanetime + "\n" + "Terminal nr. " + f.Terminal +"\n" + "Parking slot: " + f.Parkingslot);}
        else{
       System.out.println("Cannot find flight");
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

The while loop in your find method stops once it finds a match. The proper way to do what you are asking is:

1. Create an object that will store your results
2. Each time you find a result, instead of returning it immediately, like you are right now, put it on the temporary storage
3. Once you reach the end of your list, return your storage object. If it's empty, there were no results

Comment: I;m kind of new to objects/methods/lists.

Comment: Which language is this? Tag your post with the correct language you are using.

As for your question, first you must decide in what format do you want your results to come out. Say if you have 3 cities, how do you plan to return them to whatever calls find()?

Comment: Let's say I have 10 airplanes(flight number, destination, airline, timeof departure) in my linked list. if i have more  than 1 flight with the same destination when i search for that destination i want to print out all the info of all the nodes that have that destination.I added a piece of code from main that displays what find returns.